# VBA Timer that runs asynchronously while a remote query executes

Tags: vba, ms-access, winapi, asynchronous, timer

I have an Access application that pulls data from a slow SQL Server data warehouse.  I'm using VBA to call the queries with either `Docmd.OpenQuery` or `CurrentDb.Execute` (depending if they are action queries).  Some of the queries can take 5-10 minutes to run.  When a query is called I would like to display an elapsed timer on the screen, starting at "00:00:00", that increments in seconds while waiting for the query to finish.

I tried to build a form with a Timer() event but discovered that as soon as the query is called, the timer event halts.  Doing some further research I have read that this isn't possible because Access is singled threaded.  For this to work the timer and query need to run asynchronously.  My question to the community is, has anyone found a way to do this with an API call or other means that does not require additional files outside of the VBA project?  This code is part of an Access Add-in and I want it to be easily distributable and able to work on any query (slow/fast/Access/ODBC/etc.)

```
' Code might look like this:
StartTimer ' This starts and shows the timer
Docmd.OpenQuery "vw_CustomerReport" ' This calls the query.  The timer should still update while this runs.
StopTimer ' This stops the timer.
```

*Note:  I don't have any control over the speed of the database or the queries so please don't make suggestions to optimize the queries or run them as pass-through.  This question is about showing an elapsed time and not about slow queries.*

Comment: This might be possible for action queries, but I doubt it's possible for `SELECT` queries, unless you're willing to do some odd things (such as use a form in datasheet view instead of the actual query).

Comment: what do you mean "**remote** queries"?  If a processor besides yours is handling these queries, it shouldn't be a problem. Also, what is the purpose of the timer? Just to let the user know it's "working" ?

Comment: I used the word "remote query" to mean calling a pass-through query where the processing is done elsewhere. I was hoping to get a better response if I limited it that way.  Access is just twiddling its thumbs while waiting for the query to respond.
I'd actually like to have this work for any `SELECT` or action query.  The purpose of the elapsed timer is just to let the user know it is still running.   I also know how long it took to run last time (from a log entry) so it could help the user know how long they will need to wait.

Comment: You seem pretty intent on having the timer run with the query.  But also  remember that you can just check the time before and after you run the query if you're just trying to document how long the queries take.

Comment: Access is most definitely *not* single-threaded. The timer, however, likely uses the operating system's [timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592.aspx). Those timer events are only raised, when messages are dispatched. As long as you are in a blocking call, that doesn't happen. So the real reason, why the timer doesn't work is because *your* code is single-threaded.

Comment: There is a WinAPI Timer that can be used, whuch i think uses a function callback, but not sure offhand if that will interceed the query processing or just back up timer calls until the quey is finished.   I'll pull up the timer code next time im at a computer

Comment: @jleach: Calling [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) with a callback still requires, that the calling thread is dispatching messages, as explained in the "Remarks" section. As long as you are in a blocking call, the calling thread does not dispatch messages.

Comment: @jleach, I just tried using the WinAPI SetTimer with `Debug.Print` statements and they stop as soon as `Docmd.OpenQuery` is called, as foretold by IInspectable.